# Create launcher for application not in /usr/share/applications in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: launcher

I downloaded the program Zotero for Linux and it doesn't need installing, only extracting. However, the only way to start the program is by running it from a terminal.

I would really like to have a simple launcher for it. I understood I am supposed to copy a .desktop file from /usr/share/applications/ but there is no file zotero.desktop

In the downloaded program folder is a file called zotero.desktop, but I don't know what to do with it.

On the website are the following instructions, which didn't work:

> For Ubuntu, the tarball includes a .desktop file that can be used to
> add Zotero to the launcher. Move the extracted directory to a location
> of your choice (e.g., /opt/zotero), run the set_launcher_icon script
> from a terminal to update the .desktop file for that location, and
> symlink zotero.desktop into ~/.local/share/applications/ (e.g., ln -s
> /opt/zotero/zotero.desktop
> ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop). Zotero should then appear
> either in your launcher or in the applications list when click the
> grid icon (“Show Applications”), from which you can drag it to the
> launcher.

I also tried `sudo ln -s Zotero_linux-x86_64/zotero.desktop /usr/share/applications/zotero.desktop` but again nothing

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain an entry to the program in your application menu, you indeed should copy the `zotero.desktop` file to an appropriate directory, and also verify if it points to the correct executable and icon.

**1) Copy the launcher to a suitable directory**

If a Zotero `.desktop` file came with the program, then copy (or indeed link) that file in one of the directories where the system picks up these launchers:

- If you are the only user needing to run the application, copy the launcher to `~/.local/share/applications`.
- If all users need to have access and see the program in their menu, copy the launcher to `/usr/local/share/applications`. That directory may not exist by default. You could also copy to `/usr/share/applications` but that directory is rather intended to be managed by the operating system.

**2) Verify all entries in the file are valid**

Open the `.desktop` file and check if the `Exec=` and `Icon=` items point to a valid executable or icon. You can provide a full path to these files, or alternatively

- *For the executable*: link to a folder in your search path, i.e. `~/bin` or `~/.local/bin` if you are the only user needing access, or `/usr/local/bin` if you want all users to have access
- *For the icon*: place a copy of the icon in `~/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/local/share/icons` (may need to create either of these directories) for single user or multi-user installation, respectively.

Comment: Great, it worked. Thank you so much!